# Direct3D 10, failed on creating input layout

Tags: layout, input, unhandled-exception, direct3d10

My application keeps failing to compile when I try to create a Vertex Layout in direct3D 10. Heres the code:

```
// Create the vertex input layout.
D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC vertexDesc[] =
{
    {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    {"COLOR",    0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
};

// Create the input layout
D3D10_PASS_DESC PassDesc;
mTech->GetPassByIndex(0)->GetDesc(&PassDesc);
HR(md3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(vertexDesc, 2, PassDesc.pIAInputSignature,
    PassDesc.IAInputSignatureSize, &mVertexLayout));
```

It fails in `CreateInputLayout()`, I was also under the impression that `HR()` is meant to catch problems such as these and make suggestions in these cases, however it doesn't appear to do that. Although as with many cases I may be completely wrong on that. The prompt that comes up is :

> Unhandled exception at 0x757fd36f in CourseworkApp.exe: 0x0000087A: 0x87a.

I think this is mainly related to errors with pointers but I am unsure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your color format "DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM" and change "HR(md3dDevice->CreateInputLayout..." to "if(FAILED(md3dDevice->CreateInputLayout...)) {//Handle errors}".

I think that might help fix the problem.